# JS: как оттестировать скрипт обратного отсчёта?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Нужен был максимально простой скрипт обратного отсчёта времени до указанной даты. Все готовые решения, которые удалось найти, показались мне слишком сложными. Написал свой, но теперь не знаю, как проверить корректность его работы. Вроде бы показывает то, что я ожидаю:

```js
function getMyDate() {

 var nowDate = Date.now(); //текущая дата в timestamp

 var myDate = Date.parse(new Date(2018, 4, 12, 22)); //нужная дата в timestamp

 var sec = Math.round((myDate - nowDate)/1000); //общее количество оставшихся секунд
  
  var days = parseInt(sec/86400); //количество дней
  
  var hours = parseInt(sec/3600)%24; //...часов
  
  var mins = parseInt(sec/60)%60; //...минут
  
  sec = sec%60; //...секунд
  
  document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days;
  document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hours;
  document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML = mins;
  document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = sec;

}


setInterval(function() { getMyDate(); }, 1000);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2>ОСТАЛОСЬ</h2>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>дней:</td><td>часов:</td><td>минут:</td><td>секунд:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="days"></td><td id="hours"></td><td id="mins"></td><td id="sec"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет не корректно, так как после достижения даты он идет в - вот скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что бы избежать данного случая нужно редактировать скрипт так:

```js
function getMyDate() {

 var nowDate = Date.now(); //текущая дата в timestamp

 var myDate = Date.parse(new Date(2018, 4, 9, 17)); //нужная дата в timestamp

 var sec = Math.round((myDate - nowDate)/1000); //общее количество оставшихся секунд
  
  var days = parseInt(sec/86400); //количество дней
  
  var hours = parseInt(sec/3600)%24; //...часов
  
  var mins = parseInt(sec/60)%60; //...минут
  
  sec = sec%60; //...секунд
  // ниже проверяем не отрицательные ли данные.
  if( sec >= 0 && mins >= 0 && hours >= 0 && days >= 0) {
    document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days;
    document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hours;
    document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML = mins;
    document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = sec;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = 0;
    document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = 0;
    document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML = 0;
    document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = 0;
  }
}


setInterval(function() { getMyDate(); }, 1000);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2>ОСТАЛОСЬ</h2>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>дней:</td><td>часов:</td><td>минут:</td><td>секунд:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="days"></td><td id="hours"></td><td id="mins"></td><td id="sec"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: О, точно! Спасибо. Про уход в минус я как-то даже не подумал. А больше никаких косяков нет? Логика в принципе верная?

Comment: Да, логика верная, просто в  `-`  уходил , а так порядок.

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки можно подменять текущую дату/время на фейковые:

```js
{
  // Машина времени!
  let diff;
  let orig = Date.now.bind(Date);
  Date.now = () => orig() + 
    (diff ? diff : 0);
  
  document.getElementById('fakeDTBtn')
   .addEventListener('click', 
     () => {
       diff = new Date(document.getElementById('DTNow').value).getTime() - orig();
     })
}

// Ниже оригинальный код
function getMyDate() {

 var nowDate = Date.now(); //текущая дата в timestamp

 var myDate = Date.parse(new Date(2018, 4, 12, 22)); //нужная дата в timestamp

 var sec = Math.round((myDate - nowDate)/1000); //общее количество оставшихся секунд
  
  var days = parseInt(sec/86400); //количество дней
  
  var hours = parseInt(sec/3600)%24; //...часов
  
  var mins = parseInt(sec/60)%60; //...минут
  
  sec = sec%60; //...секунд
  
  document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days;
  document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hours;
  document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML = mins;
  document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = sec;

}


setInterval(function() { getMyDate(); }, 1000);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2>ОСТАЛОСЬ</h2>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>дней:</td><td>часов:</td><td>минут:</td><td>секунд:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="days"></td><td id="hours"></td><td id="mins"></td><td id="sec"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- -->
<div>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="DTNow">
  <button id="fakeDTBtn">Выставить сейчас</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Не, фейковые даты мне ни к чему - я ведь сам вручную их задаю, а не получаю от пользователя. Мне было важно понять, корректно ли считаются дни, часы, минуты - не напутал ли я чего с логикой.

Comment: Я дал вам способ сказать скрипту что сейчас уже завтра/послезавтра. Вы спросили: "Как проверить?", я ответил: "вот - посмотрите, как ваш таймер будет выглядеть в будущем"

Comment: да, ок, спасибо!